# Factor Transition Issue

Tags: factoring

$$
F'(x)=(2ax+b)e^x+(ax^2+bx+c)e^x=(ax^2+(b+2a)x+c+b)e^x
$$

Can someone explain this? I can't understand the transition. What method is this?

Comment: please post your formulas here...and definitely dont post them in such a bad image.

Comment: Anyway, this is just the distributive law.  $Ay+By=(A+B)y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2ax+b)e^x+(ax^2+bx+c)e^x$
$=2axe^x+be^x+ax^2e^x+bxe^x+ce^x$
$=ax^2e^x+bxe^x+2axe^x+ce^x+be^x$
$=(ax^2+bx+2ax+ce+b)e^x$
$=(ax^2+(b+2a)x+c+b)e^x$